# Replace javascript on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an event:

```
javascript: AbrePesquisa ('/page/Test.asp?parm1=False');
```

The `AbrePesquisa`

```
function: 
AbrePesquisa function (url) 
{
url = url.replace = ("?" , "$$$");
... 
}
```

In the IE, the url is coming with `"$$$"` ('/page/Test.asp$$$parm1=False') but it comes in chrome with `"$$"` ('/page/Test.asp$$parm1=False').

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please post actual valid code. It's really hard to tell what you are trying to do otherwise. You are trying to replace `$ $ $` despite the fact that your original code doesn't contain that string? And you are missing a comma?

Comment: Too confusing.  Post real code please.

Comment: This causes a syntax error in any browser. Please post your actual code.

Comment: Still not valid code.

Comment: Also: which version of IE? Because on IE 11, I get the same result as with Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) for String.prototype.replace you'll see that $ is a special character used to include parts of the matched string in the replacement. To get what you want, you'll have to do `url.replace("?", "$$$$$$");`

Comment: Actually `url.replace("?","$\$$$$$")` (5 $) seems to work for Chrome.

Comment: But 6 `$` works on Firefox (as does 5), but not of IE (which works with 5). Seems like Firefox is the odd man out here.